# aligning text to top in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my text to align with the top of the image in the cell beside it. Vertical-align top doesn't seem to be working? I think currently it's trying to center itself relative to the other cell. Maybe there's a better way to do this with floats or something?

Here's the CSS:

```
table#body1 {
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
td#images { 
    width: 30%;
}
td#text {
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And the HTML: (all the divs are inline-block elements if that makes a difference)

```
<table id="body1">
<tr>

<td id="images"><img class="halfimg1" src="titania2.jpg" alt="Queen Titania"><br></td>
<td id="text">
<div id="header">Wander in these woods.</div><br>
This is some Text.<br>
<div id="caption"><br>This is my caption.</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Avoid using tables for layout. That's what CSS is for. Use tables for tabular data.

Comment: What's a better alternative?

Comment: <img src="titanium.jpg" alt="" />
    <div>Text goes here</div>

    <style>
    img, div {
     display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
    </style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add vertical-align: top; to td#images as well.

Comment: The text is still not aligned with the top of the image. It's sort of centered but the caption div is sort of on it's own alignment (been pushed down a bit below the bottom of the image)

Comment: Don't know how your image looks but if I try with any image it looks fine to me. Will put up a fiddle in a sec.

Comment: It works now in IE but not Firefox. Is there something I can add to get it to display in all browsers?

Comment: works in IE, Firefox and Chrome for me - what browser are you using (version)? and what Operating System?

Comment: it should work in all browsers, can you add a fiddle or a url? As mentioned before css is a better way to do this, unless you have a reason to use tables.

Comment: I'll try using CSS instead then and see if that solves it. I just use tables because I didn't know an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind the comment I made above, you probably want to move the `vertical-align: top;`  rule from `td#text` to `td#images`

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pwr8my4L/1/)**